# a commercial API key did not work: This page can't load google maps correctly

Tags: google-maps

I used a new key and got:

> "This page can't load google maps correctly"

What does it really mean?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places" async defer"></script>
```

This is a key from a commercial account.

Comment: What does the javascript console tell you?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, or a lot more details about the issue.

Comment: The error you're getting is this one: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#api-key-billing-errors

Comment: You need to enable billing on your project for the Maps APIs to work.

Comment: We did enable the billing and select "Javascript GoogleMap  API"

Comment: We also set "None" in section of "Application restrictions" in Google Cloud Platform under "APIs & Service" page. We even set the key as unrestricted

Comment: Did you also enable the Places API? As you're including the places library in your script.

Comment: In fact I can see it's not, please see my answer below. To use the Places library you need to enable it first. Hoping this resolves your issue!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who runs into this "*This page can't load google maps correctly*" error and has added the [Places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) in the JavaScript API script, i.e.:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

You must **enable the Places API**. It's not enough to enable the JavaScript API only. Refer to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#GetStarted):

> Before using the Places library in the Maps JavaScript API, first
>   ensure that the Places API is enabled in the Google Cloud Platform
>   Console, in the same project you set up for the Maps JavaScript API.

Hope this helps.