# Places Autocomplete address prediction html, when dropping it into search box it gives me a ! and i can't type

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google address form, I have looked on the internet for ages trying to implement other peoples code templates to use for my html app.

So I just grabbed google template and tried to understand if anyone could help me out that would be great.

Fortunately I got close to solving my problem but when I embed the code into my website, it gave me a "!" once I type in a letter and won't let me type anymore.

> 

```js
// This sample uses the Autocomplete widget to help the user select a
// place, then it retrieves the address components associated with that
// place, and then it populates the form fields with those details.
// This sample requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script
// src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var placeSearch, autocomplete;

var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
  // geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {types: ['geocode']});

  // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
  // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
  autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);

  // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
  // address fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details,
  // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle(
          {center: geolocation, radius: position.coords.accuracy});
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
<style>
  #locationField, #controls {
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
  }
  #autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 99%;
  }
  .label {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
    color: #303030;
    font-family: "Roboto";
  }
  #address {
    border: 1px solid #000090;
    background-color: #f0f9ff;
    width: 480px;
    padding-right: 2px;
  }
  #address td {
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  .field {
    width: 99%;
  }
  .slimField {
    width: 80px;
  }
  .wideField {
    width: 200px;
  }
  #locationField {
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete"
         placeholder="Enter your address"
         onFocus="geolocate()"
         type="text"/>
</div>

<!-- Note: The address components in this sample are typical. You might need to adjust them for
           the locations relevant to your app. For more information, see
     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
-->

<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true"/></td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route" disabled="true"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"/></td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="country" disabled="true"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

Comment: The posted code snippet works for me.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Do you have a valid API key of your own, authorized for your URL and billing enabled with a credit card?

Comment: You need to use your own valid api key from a project that has billing enabled and the JS API and Places API enabled. Please see related [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544783/this-page-cant-load-google-maps-properly) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615109/a-commercial-api-key-did-not-work-this-page-cant-load-google-maps-correctly)